# Unable to use inflate tool

Tags: sculpting

Trying to use the inflate tool on a mesh in sculpt mode. However, I am unable to make any noticeable change on the object and cannot drag my brush over it. All other sculpt tools work as expected, but I notice that the outline of my brush is grayed out, whereas the brush has either a pink or yellow outline when using other tools. My object has plenty of subdivisions so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Would it be fine if you attached the .blend file. So we could examine the curious behavior of your file? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have a strength value for the brush, a zero strength will do nothing. A strong autosmooth with a low strength can also negate the effect of some brushes.

[image]

Each brush can be set to use a different colour to outline the brush, by default inflate uses a grey while other brushes use red, green or yellow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had accidentally changed the stroke method to one I wasn't used to, which made using the tool confusing. (Yeah, the outline color didn't have anything to do with it) Thanks all for your help in narrowing down the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and it was because of the brush settings:

[image: Brush settings]